# javascript data from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, return

I am trying resolve my problem but I have no idea how to do it. I have a service:

```
this.getNews = function(token) {
    return $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        url: BASE_URL + "getNews/",
        data: { UserToken:token },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.spinnerbg').show();
        },
        complete: function (d) {
            checkPoints(d);
            // $(".spinnerbg").hide();
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Can't connect to server. Please try again later.");
        }
    });
}
```

I know that JSON have code:

```
{
    "Spent": {
        "ever": 0, 
        "today": 0
    }, 
    "Earned": {
        "ever": 82, 
        "today": 0    
    }
}
```

I want to support this in JS I have code:

```
var Bib = function() {
    this.init = function() {
        WS.getNews(cache.get('authtoken')).done(function(data) {
            $("#today_earned").html(data['Earned']['today']);
        });
    };
}
```

This doesn't work. It gives me an empty value in HTML id. What is wrong in my code and why is this happening?

Comment: Code looks fine to me, perhaps it is a problem with the token, service, or server side?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors, and to ensure that the AJAX request is working

Comment: no problem with the token ajax is working i have a lot of  requests in code and only this doesn't working

Comment: Put `console.log(data)` in the `.done` function, and see what you're getting.

Comment: var Bib = function() {.. where you call Bib function